# replace while loop in python with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have been trying to optimize my code, which fetches the data from a given ip address and has pagination involved in it. I have tried applying multiprocessing/multithreading but can't able to implement them successfully.

My goal of using multiprocessing is to reduce the execution time. Please help me out in this.

```
        has_pagination = True 
        session_obj = some_value         #like this <requests.sessions.Session object at 0x7fac952c4fa0>
        headers = {'X-XSRF-TOKEN':token, 'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json', 'Cookie':jsessionid}


        while has_pagination:

            url = f"https://{self.ip}/data/page?count=100&scrollId={scroll_id}"
            response = session_object.get(url=url, headers=headers, verify=False)
            
            try:
                resp_json = response.json()
                data = resp_json['data']
                has_pagination = resp_json['pageInfo']['hasMoreData']
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'status code: {response.status_code}, {e}')
                
                # # Logging out if session is established
                logout_url = f'https://{self.ip}/logout?nocache=123456'
                logout_resp = session_obj.get(url=logout_url, headers=headers, verify=False, allow_redirects=False)
                print(f'Logging out. Response code: {str(logout_resp.status_code)}')

                # # Relogin
                print(f'2. Trying to re-login with connnection details Token: {str(token)}. Jsessionid: {str(jsessionid)}. Headers: {str(headers)}.')
                login_result = self.login()
                if login_result == False:
                    return False
                else:
                    number_of_relogin += 1
                    session_obj, token, jsessionid = login_result[0], login_result[1], login_result[2]
                    headers = {'X-XSRF-TOKEN':token, 'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json', 'Cookie':jsessionid}
                    logger.info(f'2. New session established with Token: {str(token)}. Jsessionid: {str(jsessionid)}. Headers: {str(headers)}')
```

Comment: If there is a major condition (`while has_pagination:`), it will be hard to turn this into a parallel process using multiprocessing. Also, how long does an individual iteration take, and what is the part that takes longest? Because with io-limited processing, multithreading or async may be more appropriate.

Comment: this whole process took 180 seconds approx. for around 4,50,000 records (10,000 record each page) total 45 pages, i want to optimize the time here.

Comment: 3 minutes for 4.5 million records doesn't seem bad at all. How many records do you want to retrieve in total?

Comment: I am getting these data without using multiprocessing, but it would be better if i am able to do it in a better way. data in future could be lot more than that.

Comment: This isn't close to being a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't see where the URL you are retrieving changes, so do you really intend to be fetching the same page repeatedly? Anyway, the next fetch seems to depend on the previous fetch, which suggests a processing that does not lend itself to multiprocessing.

Comment: yes, you are right, I have removed the "scroll_id" part from here to keep things simple. Consider the url with scrol_id for next page, and it will give the next page results.